# Why am I unable to catch discord.js promise rejections in event callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise, discord.js

So I'm making a discord bot. For simplicity's sake, here is a *very* small portion that illustrates my problem:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', async () => {
  throw new Error('Omg');
});

async function start() {
  try {
    await client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Caught the promise rejections');
  }
}

start();
```

When I run this code, I expect the output to be `Caught the promise rejections` and the process should subsequently exit. However this is not the case. Instead I get a `PromiseRejectionWarning` and the process does not exit (I have to press Ctrl-C to do so). I first thought that maybe errors in callbacks don't get propagated to code that calls them, so I made another pure JS example:

```
const client = {
  on(event, callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  },

  async login(token) {
    while (true) {
      // I assume the login method calls the callback in D.js 
      // (where else could it be called?)
      await this.callback();
      await sleep(5000);
    }
  },
};

client.on('ready', async () => {
  throw new Error('Omg');
});

async function start() {
  try {
    await client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Caught the promise rejections');
  }
}

start();
```

However in this case, the output is exactly as expected; I see the line from the catch and the process immediately exits. Without the catch I get the unhandled promise rejection errors and an unfinished process.

So my question: Why am I unable to catch promise rejections in my event callbacks (like `on('ready')`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, because your second code, is not how discord event emitter works, nor Node.js built in EventEmiter does.

The callback function for the `ready` event is not executed with an `await`, and it doesn't have a `.catch` handler attached to it, that's why you get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

When using `async` in an EventEmitter callback, you should handle the error, if you don't you'll get the warning, because no other code is handling it.

```
client.on('ready', async () => {
  try {
     throw new Error('Omg');
  } catch(e) {

  }
});
```

In your specific case, it seems that you want to trigger an error if some condition is met on 'ready'. So what you should do instead, is wrap that listener in a `Promise`.

```
function discordReady(client) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        client.once('ready', async () => {
            reject(new Error('Omg'));

            // resolve..
        }); 
    })
}


async function start() {
  try {
    await Promise.all([
        discordReady(client),
        client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN),
    ]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Caught the promise rejections');
  }
}
```

That will get you the expected behaviour

Comment: So just to clarify, you're saying that since the `on('ready')` event itself isn't handled using a `.catch`, the promise rejection is essentially ignored? In other words, does this mean that a promise rejection that occurs without the `async`/`await` keywords not propagate as well without an explicit `reject` from the calling code?

Comment: Also would you recommend going with the second approach you mentioned or just catching the errors in each individual error handler?

Comment: I'm saying that unless you catch the error inside the `on('ready')` callback, an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning will be triggered, because no one is catching that error, is your responsability to do so. Regarding what I recommend, depends on what you're trying to achieve, if you actually show your `ready` implementation, will be easier to give you the best solution.

Comment: My whole ready function is too large, but the idea is that if I somehow miss catching  an unhandled promise in any callback (on ready, on message), it gets caught at some higher level (in the try catch block surrouding the `.login` method). This way, there aren't any unexpected process exits in such a scenario (just some logging). The message does say that in the future, such errors will cause exits. I see now that my approach isn't really possible without wrapping a try-catch around the code of every callback. Thanks for clarifying anyway.